# How to generate a random invoice number

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

How do I get the random invoice number to display in the form?

I have built a WordPress site that will have a donation form. I do not want the user to be able to edit the code so I have added being added to the site via a shortcode. Since it is included as a short code I have to escape `"`. Could that be the reason the random number is not replacing the value of **UMinvoice**?

I notice that the value for UMinvoice returns as `value=` in the source code unless I add a blank space `value=\" \"`

**EDIT**: I have removed this from the short code and placed it in a custom template. All slashes have been removed. I am now getting 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByName("UMinvoice")[0].value = random_num')

The script I have creating a random invoice number is

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var d = new Date();
function f(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; }  
var random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99999999999 -  10000000000)) + 10000000000;
random_num = d.getFullYear() + f(d.getMonth()+1) + f(d.getDate()) + random_num; 
document.getElementById("invoice")[0].value = random_num;
</script>
```

The form I am using is (*the portion with the invoice input*)

```
<form id="donation" action="https://secureurl" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="UMkey" value="key" />
<input type="hidden" name="UMcustreceipt" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="UMinvoice" id="invoice" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rand = 10;

document.getElementsByName("UMinvoice")[0].value = rand;
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/P3vtD/

you will have to [strip the slashes out](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)
it is not legal html code.

this is also not legal js code: `document.form.UMinvoice.value`

If you have jquery it goes like that:

```
$('[name="UMinvoice"]').val(rand);
```

Comment: I tested my code in your jsfiddle link and everything worked, but for some reason I am getting a `undefined is not an object (evaluating document.getElementsByName("UMinvoice")[0].value = random_num)` error. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ChasesWork Can you post it in js fiddle so i can see it (see my edits about jquery)?

Comment: In troubleshooting I changed **getElementsByName()** to **getElementById()** and when I reverted back to your example, forgot the "s" in Elements. This works in JSFiddle so I am accepting the answer. I am still receiving the `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByName("UMinvoice")[0].value = random_num')` in Wordpress. Any thoughts on how to track down the issue are appreciated. Thank you for you help.

Comment: I will have to see that code in order to really evaluate it, it sounds like returning null. try to `console.log(document.getElementsByName("UMinvoice"))` and see in chrome  dev tool what is the result

Comment: the console returns `TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`.

Comment: I am sorry, it is impossible to investigate it (try to bring the error to js fiddle). I can offer 2 things. one, use jQuery if you can. two - add id to each input tag and access it with getElementById

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
```